# Newly installed Windows drive not booting on its own; needs old SSD installed

Tags: windows, boot, ssd

I was using Windows 10 on a SATA SSD. I decided to install Windows 11 on an NVMe using a Windows 11 ISO file that I flashed onto an external drive.

However, I noticed that the Windows 11 installation on my NVMe did not boot up by itself—it would go straight into the BIOS. Now when I want to boot into my NVMe, I need to connect my old SATA SSD to my computer, turn it on, and then select Windows 11 as my boot option (from choices of Win 11 and Win 10).

Why is the UEFI not recognizing my NVMe as a bootable disk even though I can run Windows just fine on it? How do I make it so that it can boot into Windows on its own without my needing to keep the old SSD plugged in?

Comment: @Ramhound So I would need to reinstall Windows 11 on the NVMe with my old SATA drive both connected, as well as my Windows 11 installation drive? Wouldn't this get rid of all my data, or can I do a "repair" or "upgrade" installation?

Comment: You said "the solution to this problem is to reinstall Windows 11"?